# YUI2 DataTable Allow Cell Contents to 'Bleed' from One Column to Next

Tags: datatable, overflow, html-table, yui2

Using http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_basic.html as the base, simply add a new column to the end of the table. Next, resize the title column so that the width of the column is smaller than the width of the contents of the column.

What I'm trying to do: If there is no data in the column to the right of the title column and the contents of the title column are wider than the column itself, I would like the display of the title column to continue into the next column if adjacent cell column is empty.

It seems that 'overflow: hidden' might be the source of my problem. When I re-size the column, it seems this CSS gets reset from visible. More clues I guess.

An 'inline style' of 'overflow: hidden;' appears to be added from somewhere/thing when you adjust the column width via drag and drop.

Is there a CSS trick or something to fix/allow this with YUI2 tables?